# Warnings C4995 when adding #include <vector> to MFC project

Tags: c++, stl, mfc

I'm trying to add `#include <vector>` to my MFC project. It compiles, but I get the following warnings (just some of them, the actual list is much longer):

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(49) : warning C4995: 'gets': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(53) : warning C4995: 'sprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstdio(56) : warning C4995: 'vsprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstring(22) : warning C4995: 'strcat': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cstring(23) : warning C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cwchar(36) : warning C4995: 'swprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cwchar(37) : warning C4995: 'vswprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cwchar(39) : warning C4995: 'wcscat': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\cwchar(41) : warning C4995: 'wcscpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
```

I can silence it by doing this:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4995)
#include <vector>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

But I'm curious to know why the library causes those warnings? And if there's a better way to fix this other than suppressing warnings?

Comment: Try adding `#define STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE` before any includes in your `stdafx.h`. Or add it to the define list in your project settings. I don't believe this is needed since at-least VS2010. It looks like you're using VS2008. MS wants you using `"safe"` versions of the functions mentioned (`strcat_s`, `sprintf_s`, etc). I find it odd their standard lib doesn't do this by default. You're not mixing standard libraries from other VS versions, right?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't think I do. I'll try to play with adding `#define STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE`. The thing is knowing which include of `stdafx.h` is called first. They are pretty much in every `.cpp` file.

Comment: I meant put it *in* `stdafx.h` *before* any other includes included in `stdafx.h`, in case that wasn't clear. And as I said, it may be easier to just edit the project settings, and set it (both debug and release build configs) in the preprocessor defines under C/C++ settings.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Oh, I see your point. Although that would do a similar thing to my warning suppression but on a global scale. So I was curious how can I get a newer version of `std::vector` library that uses all those safe-APIs that Microsoft suggests with that warning?

Comment: It won't suppress *all* deprecations, only those surrounding the `strsafe` library. Other non-related deprecations will still be flagged. Personally I'd upgrade at least to VS2010, or VS2013.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Hmm. So I have to buy the whole new VS to get it updated, hah?

Comment: Fyi, VS2013 Community Edition is a freebie.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yeah, but does it come with MFC?

Comment: Good point. Not to my knowledge. I don't think MFC has come with any freebie VS version. You need the Pro version or better. Ironic since the upgrade price is around $800, and you couldn't pay *me* $800 to write MFC code.

Answer (score 0):

This warning mean the function that has been marked as obsolete, which may no longer be supported in a future release.

So you can have two ways to deal with it: First is the way you use, marking it with pragma deprecated, or you can use their safe version.

For example, Strcpy has a corresponding function called StringCchCopy/StringCbCopy, and get has the get_s. You can find them from MSDN.

Good luck. :)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not writing that library. Those functions come from `std::vector`.

Comment: Will this warning disappear if you don't use `std::vector`?